# Setting the authorization header stops angular material template from loading with a 401 response

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, angular-material

I have an unsecured MVC application with an angular front end, that talks to a secured Web API. Security is handled with Json web tokens.

I am using a $http injector with transformRequest to add an access token to every http request:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$injector', "$cookies", "$http", function ($rootScope, $injector, $cookies, $http) {
    $injector.get("$http").defaults.transformRequest = $injector.get("$http").defaults.transformRequest.concat([function (data, headersGetter) {
        $rootScope.accessToken = $cookies["access_token"];
        if ($rootScope.accessToken) {
            headersGetter()['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + $rootScope.accessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when communicating with a secured api and angular templates load without issue from my mvc app. However, when using the angular material $mddDialog, the templateUrl does not correctly load the template, instead a 401 error is returned. This is very odd, because I do not have any security on my MVC application.

Comment: Can you inspect the network requests to double check what URL is being requested?

Comment: I have done this. From chrome developer tools, I can click on the network request and the template opens in a new tab without issue. I have also inspected it on Fiddler and can't see anything unusual there